# Get-NetConnectionProfile IPv4Connectivity paramater

Tags: powershell

(Get-NetConnectionProfile).IPv4Connectivity

has outputs that can be:

```
Disconnected
NoTraffic
Subnet
LocalNetwork
Internet
```

lets see if I can ask this such that it makes sense:

A couple of these are obvious in terms of internet access, for example, 'Disconnected' would mean no internet access because its disconnected and 'Internet' obviously means internet access. If the system is connected to a local network or is a subnet'd system or shows 'no traffic' but does have access to the internet should the return be 'Internet' even though there is no traffic and/or its local network and/or its subnet'd ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a powershell question (in fact, it probably belongs more in server fault or something) because this is something that we get from the operating system API.

- Disconnected should mean that a NIC is disabled at the software level
- NoTraffic should mean that the NIC has detected some sort of hardware fault, like ethernet cable not plugged in
- Subnet should mean that there is some sort of workgroup or APIPA connection
- LocalNetwork should mean that the NIC has joined an intranet
- Internet should mean that the internet is available through a local network connection.

This is also a sort of pseudo-troubleshooting-stack ala OSI. Each step belongs to a theoretical layer that an IPv4 connection might be failing at. (since all but "Disconnected" are a measure of success, each successful layer denotes a potential problem with the next one.)

- Disconnected: Physical Problems
- NoTraffic: Link layer problems
- Subnet: Network problems
- LocalNetwork: Transport problems
- Internet: Application problems